# Generate the rank/number if the difference between consecutive rows is less than 10 days

Tags: hive

Need **hive query** that calculates the date difference for consecutive records but for the same txn type and generate same number if the difference is less than 10 else generate new number.

## Input table

```
+--------+----------+-------------+
| Txn_id | Txn_type |  Txn_date   |
+--------+----------+-------------+
|      1 | T100     | 26-Aug-2015 |
|      2 | T100     | 03-Nov-2015 |
|      3 | T100     | 05-Dec-2015 |
|      4 | T100     | 08-Dec-2015 |
|      5 | T100     | 25-Jan-2016 |
|      6 | T111     | 26-Jan-2016 |
|      7 | T200     | 02-Feb-2016 |
|      8 | T200     | 07-May-2016 |
|      9 | T200     | 12-May-2016 |
|     10 | T200     | 20-May-2016 |
+--------+----------+-------------+
```

## Expected output

```
+--------+----------+-------------+--------+
| Txn_id | Txn_type |  Txn_date   | Number |
+--------+----------+-------------+--------+
|      1 | T100     | 26-Aug-2015 |      1 |
|      2 | T100     | 03-Nov-2015 |      2 |
|      3 | T100     | 05-Dec-2015 |      3 |
|      4 | T100     | 08-Dec-2015 |      3 |
|      5 | T100     | 25-Jan-2016 |      4 |
|      6 | T111     | 26-Jan-2016 |      1 |
|      7 | T200     | 02-Feb-2016 |      1 |
|      8 | T200     | 07-May-2016 |      2 |
|      9 | T200     | 12-May-2016 |      2 |
|     10 | T200     | 20-May-2016 |      2 |
+--------+----------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? Perhaps you should visit [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you gotta ask a question if you want an answer.... And, if you are asking us to write your code. SO doesn't approve at that, SO is meant to help find the reason and fix for a problem in code.

Comment: You forgot to add part explaining *problem* you are having while writing **your** code for posted requirements. Use [edit] option to update your question with that missed part.

Comment: @Pshemo But the question is really interesting. I still can not think of how it is achieved by means of Oracle

Comment: What is an "access" query? Do you mean Microsoft Access?

Comment: @Mike You may be right. I observe Java tag and when I see questions like "this is my input, I want to get this result" I see it as code-writing request which I consider off-topic. Since I am not sure about etiquette in SQL tag I will retract my vote.

Comment: @Pshemo - your instinct is generally right. Forum members use their judgment - sometimes a question is obviously homework or generally an easy question, where we expect to see some effort on the OP's part. Sometimes (as in this example) the solution may not be obvious; we write solutions to help the OP, but also future forum visitors who may have similar questions. In such cases we may relax the "show us your work first" requirement. Thanks for caring though, either way!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if "less than 10 days" means strict or non-strict inequality, but otherwise:

```
with
     inputs ( txn_id, txn_type, txn_date ) as (
       select  1, 'T100', to_date('26-Aug-2015', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select  2, 'T100', to_date('03-Nov-2015', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all 
       select  3, 'T100', to_date('05-Dec-2015', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select  4, 'T100', to_date('08-Dec-2015', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select  5, 'T100', to_date('25-Jan-2016', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select  6, 'T111', to_date('26-Jan-2016', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select  7, 'T200', to_date('02-Feb-2016', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select  8, 'T200', to_date('07-May-2016', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select  9, 'T200', to_date('12-May-2016', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual union all
       select 10, 'T200', to_date('20-May-2016', 'dd-Mon-yy') from dual
     ),
     prep ( txn_id, txn_type, txn_date, ct ) as (
       select txn_id, txn_type, txn_date, 
              case when txn_date < lag(txn_date) over (partition by txn_type
                           order by txn_date) + 10 then 0 else 1 end
       from   inputs
     )
select txn_id, txn_type, txn_date, 
       sum(ct) over (partition by txn_type order by txn_date) as number_
from prep;
```

I used `number_` as a column name; don't use reserved Oracle words for table or column names unless your life depends on it, and not even then.

Answer (score 0):

Use a common table expression to mark the rows that have a difference of more than 10 days and then count those to get the new number.

```
with test_data as (
 SELECT 1 txn_id, 'T100' txn_type, to_date('26-AUG-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') txn_date from dual union all
 SELECT 2 txn_id, 'T100', to_date('03-NOV-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union all
 SELECT 3 txn_id, 'T100', to_date('05-DEC-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union all
 SELECT 4 txn_id, 'T100', to_date('08-DEC-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union all
 SELECT 5 txn_id, 'T100', to_date('25-JAN-2016','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union all
 SELECT 6 txn_id, 'T111', to_date('26-JAN-2016','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union all
 SELECT 7 txn_id, 'T200', to_date('02-FEB-2016','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union all
 SELECT 8 txn_id, 'T200', to_date('07-MAY-2016','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union all
 SELECT 9 txn_id, 'T200', to_date('12-MAY-2016','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual union all
 SELECT 10 txn_id, 'T200', to_date('20-MAY-2016','DD-MON-YYYY') from dual),
 markers as (
select td.*, 
       case when td.txn_date - nvl(lag(td.txn_date) 
           over ( partition by txn_type order by txn_id ), td.txn_date-9999) > 10 
           THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL end new_txn_marker from test_data td )
SELECT txn_id, txn_type,txn_date, 
       count(new_txn_marker) over ( partition by txn_type order by txn_id ) "NUMBER" 
FROM  markers;
```